# Navigating to tabs page not working

Tags: ionic3

I'm fairly new to Ionic and it's new navigation.

I'm trying to navigate to the tabs page displaying a particular page.

I am using the following code to go from the current page to the tabs, but the tabs are not displaying. I'm referencing the Tabs controller name.

```
if(this.auth.isAuthenticated){
  this.navCtrl.push('TabsPage'); 
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: please update your code...

Comment: did you try `this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);`  and `import {TabsPage} from 'yourpath' ;`